# Adding two single Cluster Controller to a MaaS Region Controller

Tags: maas

I'd like to realize an infrastructure using Ubuntu 14.04Lts like this:

- 1 Region Controller (RC), Ubuntu 14.04 Server Edition
- 2 Cluster Controller(CC), Ubuntu 14.04 Server Edition

MaaS has been installed via Ubuntu ISO and then upgraded using ppa stable, while on two Cluster Controller I've installed only maas-cluster-controller and maas-dhcp maas-dns.

All Servers are on the same network.

When I try to add the two CC on the RC I don't see any pending cluster

[image]

I've found this solution [Connect cluster controller to the region controller (MaaS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580784/connect-cluster-controller-to-the-region-controller-maas) but when I tried to run this command

**`$: sudo maas-provision install-shared-secret`**

I've received this error

```
usage: __main__.py [-h] [-c FILENAME]
                   {atomic-write,customize-config,generate-dhcp-config,install-uefi-config,start-cluster-controller,upgrade-cluster}
                   ...
__main__.py: error: invalid choice: 'install-shared-secret' (choose from u'atomic-write', u'customize-config', u'generate-dhcp-config', u'install-uefi-config', u'start-cluster-controller', u'upgrade-cluster')
```

I've also found this command on the changelog of MaaS  (http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/changelog.html), the note says that:

*"RPC security. As a step towards mutually verified TLS connections between MAAS’s components, 1.7 introduces a simple shared-secret mechanism to authenticate the region with the clusters and vice-versa. For those clusters that run on the same machine as the region controller (which will account for most people), everything will continue to work without intervention. However, if you’re running a cluster on a separate machine, you must install the secret: After upgrading the region controller, view /var/lib/maas/secret (it’s text) and copy it. On each cluster, run:
    sudo -u maas maas-provision install-shared-secret
You’ll be prompted for the secret; paste it in and press enter. It is a password prompt, so the secret will not be echoed back to you. That’s it; the upgraded cluster controller will find the secret without needing to be told."*

I've also run that and the error is different

**`$: sudo -u maas maas-provision install-shared-secret`**

```
This utility may only be run as root.
```

why ???

I've also open this ask some months ago showing the same issue

[How to add a new cluster controller to MaaS release 1.7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554284/how-to-add-a-new-cluster-controller-to-maas-release-1-7)

I'd like to close that, any suggests to resolve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved that upgraded MaaS with its own last release and following this procedure.

***- On Region Controller run:***

> **$: cat /var/lib/maas/secret**

copy the key

***- On Cluster Controller run:***

> **$: sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-cluster-controller**

and adding the key copied from Region Controller, then after few second we'll see the new Cluster Controller on MaaS UI.

[image]
s

[image]

[image]

then on UI

[image]