# How to add a new cluster controller to MaaS release 1.7?

Tags: maas

I've a MaaS ver 1.7 upgraded via stable ppa and I'd like to add a new Cluster Controller, both of them are on the same network. 
When I tried to run that command on a Cluster Controller:

**`sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-cluster-controller`**

on Region Controller dashboard don't see any new cluster in pending.

[image]

I've also open anther new "Ask" because I've try to follow a solution reported on changelog of Maas but without results.

Has anyone tried to add another Cluster on a Region?

[Error with MaaS Region Controller and two single Cluster Controller](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484951/error-with-maas-region-controller-and-two-single-cluster-controller)

Comment: anyone can help me to resolve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the solution here:

[Adding two single Cluster Controller to a MaaS Region Controller](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484951/adding-two-single-cluster-controller-to-a-maas-region-controller)