# Connect cluster controller to the region controller (MaaS)

Tags: server, apt, dns, maas

I'm trying to build a MaaS cluster and this is what I've done so far:

***Region Controller***

- install ubuntu 14.10
- configure interfaces
- configure dns
- `apt update`
- `apt upgrade`
- `apt install maas-region-controller`
- `dpkg-reconfigure maas-region-controller` ----> http://192.168.10.1/MAAS/
- create new root account
- login

***Cluster Controller***

- install ubuntu 14.10
- configure interfaces
- configure dns
- `apt update`
- `apt upgrade`
- `apt install maas-cluster-controller`
- `dpkg-reconfigure maas-cluster-controller` ----> 192.168.10.1
- `maas login <maas_user> http://192.168.10.1/MAAS/ <api_key>`

Check MaaS web interface... **no clusters appear in the clusters tab.** Just to confirm they are on the same network.  regardless I can log into maas from the cluster controller... but it doesn't seem to make a difference in the outcome.

I've been troubleshooting this for 4 days now and its getting rough.... does anyone know what makes these two communicate properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first clue to the answer lies in the log /var/log/maas/pserv.log on the cluster-controller.  The problem was essentially an authentication failure.

```
2015-02-02 20:36:57+0900 [Uninitialized] ClusterClient connection established (HOST:IPv4Address(TCP, '172.16.10.3', 46209) PEER:IPv4Address(TCP, u'172.16.10. 1', 39492)) 
2015-02-02 20:36:57+0900 [Uninitialized] Event-loop maas:pid=1814 (127.0.0.1:33547): Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
```

The second clue came from the region-controller's /var/log/maas/apache2/error.log.

```
[Mon Feb 02 18:02:10.106725 2015] [:error] [pid 31259:tid 140386414548864] OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "maas"
[Mon Feb 02 18:02:10.106731 2015] [:error] [pid 31259:tid 140386414548864] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "maas"
```

For those that are curious I changed up my IP scheme to my eth0 interfaces which is the cause for the disparity but that did not fix anything.

This is likely a bug as in general this should happen... however the node should still show up in MaaS as pending waiting for administrator approval.

Once approval is given (from my understanding of how the system should work) the `/var/lib/maas/secret` password is transmitted from the region-controller to the cluster-controller.

Unfortunately the server never hits the pending state so this may not be performed.  Therefore what must be done to resolve this issue is to transfer your secret manually through the following commands:

***Region Controller***

```
cat /var/lib/maas/secret
```

Copy the output it should be a ~16 digit hex code. Then on your cluster controller run the following command and enter your copied "secret".

***Cluster Controller***

```
maas-provision install-shared-secret
```

lastly connect to the server through an API query of your choice (this probably isn't necessary but it does force the connection).

```
My Configurations thus far.

1. Assign Basic Network Settings to CCs and RC
a) Assign an IP from the Management LAN XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
b) configure interface XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX and XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

2. Install and configure MaaS
a) apt update && apt upgrade && apt install -y maas-region-controller ubuntu-cloudimage-keyring openssh-server
b) dpkg-reconfigure maas-region-controller
c) sudo maas-region-admin createadmin (use this account to access the web interface)
d) Create and install public key into maas profile
e) ssh-keygen -t rsa -C maas@maas.maas
f) cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub and put the output into the add sshkey page on maas
g) (cluster-controller) apt install -y libvirt-bin maas-cluster-controller

3. Configure MaaS DNS and iptables
a) in /etc/resolv.conf verify XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXis the only nameserver
b) in /etc/resolvconf/head place nameserver XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
c) (Cluster Controller) in /etc/bind/named.conf.options.* type the follwing:
"forwarders { 
 8.8.8.8;
 8.8.4.4:
};"
d) (Cluster Controller) /etc/sysctl.conf uncomment the line net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
e) (Cluster Controller)run mkdir /etc/yourorg/
f) (Cluster Controller)in /etc/init.d/rc.local write /etc/yourorg/settings.conf
g) (Cluster Controller)create file /etc/yourorg/settings.conf in vim and include:

"#!/bin/bash

/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT"

4. Install MaaS shared secret on any distributed clusters.
a) sudo cat /var/lib/maas/secret  (On region controller)
b) maas-provision install-shared-secret (Cluster Controller)
<paste secret>
```

Comment: I've tried that but in my case it has not been a solution. I've installed that using Ubuntu 14.04Lts and the error has been that http://paste.ubuntu.com/10785524/

Comment: Can you try this manually? I believe the shared secrets are stored in the same location on the region and the cluster so you should be able to copy paste and then finalize it with an API query to the master.

Comment: The path /var/lib/maas/secret on Cluster doesn't exist, it's present only on Region. I've also open an Ask to have further support (http://askubuntu.com/questions/484951/error-adding-two-single-cluster-controller-to-maas-region-controller)

Comment: to be honest I gave up on MaaS because of little issues like this cropping up all over the place.  Although I didn't have your specific issues, in particular I had issues installing OSes other than Ubuntu.  I switched over to Cobbler which is admittedly more difficult to initially setup, but is much more flexible and most of my issues have been solved.  I can however give you my notes on MaaS and hopefully that helps?? :(

Comment: Updated my fix with the notes I had compiled for my build.  I'm not going to say that everything is best practice but, it works... and can be tweaked from there to add what is needed.

Comment: I've resolved that, here the solution http://askubuntu.com/questions/484951/adding-two-single-cluster-controller-to-a-maas-region-controller

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem due to another process already listening on port 69 (tftpd).

It was reported in the log file for the `maas-clusterd` service in `/var/log/maas/clusterd.log`

> 2016-03-15 13:56:15+1000 [-] twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on 10.0.3.1:69: [Errno 98] Address already in use.

which was causing the process to die and be respawned constantly by Upstart.

To fix, I simply stopped the existing tftpd.